# Quarkus Gradle Multi-Project-Build Modular Testing Build-Problem

Tags: gradle, quarkus

I have a Grade Multi-Project Build, that consist of following projects:

- fk_core
- fk_database
- fk_product
- fk_backend

In the project `fk_product` i have defined a `QuarkusTest` that starts up a Testcontainers-Database and tests a Rest-Endpoint in this project.

To make this possible i needed to define the quarkus-plugin within this project:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'io.quarkus'
}
```

When i start the Gradle-Build via `./gradlew build` a new error now occurs. My assumption is, that it is happening during the execution of the Tests during the Build, as the first line indicated that liquibase migrations are executing / have been executed and afterwards the error appears.

My Problem now is, that i need to define an almost empty `src/main/resources/application.properties` file in the `fk_product` project, that only contains the following line:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mariadb
```

then the error during the build goes away, and the tests also run correctly (btw: My Test uses a `QuarkusTestProfile` to override configurations to startup a Testcontainers Mariadb, which works fine.

Here is the problematic console-log of the build:

```
Error: 1146-42S02: Table testshop.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK doesnt exist
The Agroal dependency is present but no JDBC datasources have been defined.
> Task :fk_product:quarkusAppPartsBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':fk_product:quarkusAppPartsBuild'.
> There was a failure while executing work items
   > A failure occurred while executing io.quarkus.gradle.tasks.worker.BuildWorker
      > io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
                [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource and qualifiers [@Default]
                - injection target: org.fk.core.jooq.ConfigurationFactory#dataSource
                - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.fk.core.jooq.ConfigurationFactory, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.fk.core.jooq.ConfigurationFactory]
```

I'm using:

- plugin "io.quarkus" '3.8.2'
- quarkus: '3.8.2'

can someone give me a hint, what i can do to fix the build without the need of the additional `application.properties` file ? As i use a `QuarkusTestProfile` i expect this to be fully functional for the tests without any additional config-files.